# Firebase - emulators start but attempt to view hosting emulator throws error in log

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

On running firebase emulators:start, everything loads up correctly. I currently have an express web app deployed to firebase using cloud functions combined with firebase hosting, and my code is identical on my local machine. When I attempt to emulate it, I can access the hub but hosting throws the below error on an attempted load:

```
>  Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, uv_pipe_open
>      at Object._forkChild (node:child_process:175:5)
>      at setupChildProcessIpcChannel (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:451:30)
>      at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:71:3)
>      at node:internal/main/run_main_module:9:1 {
>    errno: -4083,
>    code: 'EBADF',
>    syscall: 'uv_pipe_open'
```

These are the contents of my firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "public": "static",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "runtime": "nodejs16",
      "source": "/functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

My file tree is as so:

```
├── firebase.json
├── firestore-debug.log
├── firestore.indexes.json
├── firestore.rules
├── functions
│   ├── firebase-debug.log
│   ├── firestore-debug.log
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.pug
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── ui-debug.log
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── main.pug
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── static
│   ├── android-chrome-192x192.png
│   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   ├── browserconfig.xml
│   ├── css
│   │   └── styles.css
│   ├── favicon-16x16.png
│   ├── favicon-32x32.png
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── firebaseComponents.js
│   │   └── getUserState.js
│   ├── mstile-150x150.png
│   ├── safari-pinned-tab.svg
│   ├── site.webmanifest
│   ├── tapewinder_draft1.png
│   ├── tapewinder_draft3.png
│   ├── tapewinder_placeholder.png
│   ├── tapewinder_placeholder_blue.png
│   ├── tapewinder_placeholder_green.png
│   ├── tapewinder_placeholder_orange.png
│   ├── tapewinder_placeholder_pink.png
│   ├── tapewinder_placeholder_raisin.png
│   ├── tapewinder_placeholder_red.png
│   └── tapewinder_whitebg.png
├── storage.rules
└── ui-debug.log
```

I stashed all changes since my last deploy to firebase, messed with my firebase.json and so far no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem! I updated my version of node using `npm i node@latest` and everything started working again just fine.